# jQuery get this element's children by click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an html code:

```
<div class="customers-otziv__content items">
                            
                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo"> 
                                    <img data-id="1" src="girl1.jpg"  class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>

                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo">
                                    <img data-id="2" src="girl2.jpg" class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>

                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo">     
                                    <img data-id="3" src="girl3.jpg"  class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>    
 
</div>
<div class="customers-otziv__content items">
                            
                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo"> 
                                    <img data-id="4" src="girl4.jpg"  class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>

                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo">
                                    <img data-id="5" src="girl5.jpg" class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>

                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo">     
                                    <img data-id="6" src="girl6.jpg"  class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>    
 
</div>
<div class="listblock-otziv"></div>
```

So I want to get list of img sources only of this element's closest parent image children and append them to listblock-otziv:

```
    data_otziv = $(this).closest('.customers-otziv__content .items').map((i, el) => ({
        src: $(el).find('.reviews-photo').prop('src'),
    })).get();

        $.map( data_otziv, function( item, i ) {
        $(".listblock-otziv").append(`
            <div class="listblock-otziv__content" data-id="${i}">
                <img  class="listblock-otziv__photo" src="${item.src}">
            </div>`
            );
        })
```

But I am getting only one images's src value)!
Please help!

Comment: Your code has multiple problem, one is diffrence between `reviews__photo` and `reviews-photo` in html and js.

Comment: What is `$(this)` in your context, how is this code triggered?  There are no `.items` inside `.customers-otziv__content`, so that selector will not match anything.  If you meant the element that has both those classes, the selector would be without the space: `('.customers-otziv__content.items')`.

Comment: What should i do to get this clicked image's parent's img srcs only?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking: *"this clicked image's parent's img src"*?  Images can't have nested elements, so there won't be a "parent image".  The image's parent (with exact context of `this`) is class 'customers-otziv__photo' which doesn't have an image.  Your best bet is to ask a new question specifying exactly what you want to extract, ideally with an example.

Comment: @Don't Panic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74362321/jquery-nested-mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is that `.closest('.customers-otziv__content .items')` is the same as `.closest('.customers-otziv__content").find(".items')` which you don't want.  Change to

```
...closest('.customers-otziv__content.items')...
```

Secondly: `$(el).find('.reviews__photo').prop('src')` will always give you the first `src=` because prop returns a string not an array (.text() works differently here).   You need to .map to get them all out.

Easiest is to map the `.reviews__photo` elements directly:

```
$(this).closest('.customers-otziv__content.items').find(".reviews__photo").map((i, el) => ({
    src: $(el).prop('src')
})).get();
```

Thirdly, if you doing that then there appears to be no need for the interim array `data_otziv` as `i` will be the same `i` and `item` will be the same as `el`.  Switching between jquery `.map((i, el)` and array `.map((item,i)`.

Comment: 1) How did You find this :Secondly: $(el).find('.reviews__photo').prop('src') will always give you the first src= because prop returns a string not an array (.text() works differently here). You need to .map to get them all out.? 2) How can I find which javascript code line executed when I click on somethins or page loads?

Comment: I knew this already.   But it *is* explained on the jquery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/prop/  "*The .prop() method gets the property value for only the **first** element in the matched set*"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74362321/jquery-nested-mapping Please help also there