# Jquery: Nested mapping

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to map through each customers-otziv__content class and for each this class hide images and write to last child text "+more{number} images".
When I am trying this Jquery ocde. I am getting error like: Query.Deferred exception: $(...)[i].find is not a function TypeError: $(...)[i].find is not a function.
I have this HTML:

```
<div class="customers-otziv__content">
                            
                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo"> 
                                    <img data-id="1" src="girl1.jpg"  class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>

                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo">
                                    <img data-id="2" src="girl2.jpg" class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>

                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo">     
                                    <img data-id="3" src="girl3.jpg"  class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>    
 
</div>
<div class="customers-otziv__content">
                            
                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo"> 
                                    <img data-id="4" src="girl4.jpg"  class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>

                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo">
                                    <img data-id="5" src="girl5.jpg" class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>

                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo">     
                                    <img data-id="6" src="girl6.jpg"  class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>    
</div>
<div class="customers-otziv__content">
                            
                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo"> 
                                    <img data-id="7" src="girl7.jpg"  class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>

                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo">
                                    <img data-id="8" src="girl8.jpg" class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>

                            <div class="customers-otziv__photo">     
                                    <img data-id="9" src="girl9.jpg"  class="reviews__photo">
                            </div>    
 
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
let images_otziv = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
    let last_child_index;
    let other_qty = 0;    
    let content_width = $(document).find('.customers-otziv__content').width();

    content_list = $(document).find('.customers-otziv__content').map((i, el) => ({  
        content: $(el),
    })).get();

    $.map( content_list, function( item, i ) {
        console.log(i);
        console.log(777); 

        images_otziv = $('.customers-otziv__content')[i].map((i, el) => ({  
            img: $(el).find('.reviews__photo'),
        })).get();

        $.map( images_otziv, function( item, i ) {
            let img_width = $(item.img).width();       
            let content_temp_width = content_width - img_width;   
            if((content_temp_width) > img_width) {
                last_child_index = i + 1;
                $(item.img).show();
            } else {
                $(item.img).closest('.customers-otziv__photo').hide();
                other_qty = other_qty + 1;
            } 
            content_width = content_temp_width;
        }) 
        if(other_qty >= 1) {
                $('.customers-otziv__photo[data-id=' + last_child_index + ']').find('.reviews__photo').css('opacity', '0.5');
                $('.customers-otziv__photo[data-id=' + last_child_index + ']').append(`<div class="centered" style="display:none" id="haveMore">+ещё ${other_qty}</div>`);
                $('.customers-otziv__photo[data-id=' + last_child_index + ']').attr("id", "lastElem");
            }
                $("#haveMore").attr("style", "position:absolute; top:60%; font-size: 20px; z-index:999");*/

    })  
});
```

Please help!

Comment: `$(...)[i].find` - with `[i]` you make it return the plain HTMLElementObject, so you are _not_ dealing with a jQuery instance any more. Use https://api.jquery.com/eq/ to access an element from your selection via index, but still _as_ a jQuery object.

Comment: There's no `$(..)[i].find` in your provided code.   You do have: `$('.customers-otziv__content')[i].map((i, el)` which seems counter-productive as `$('.customers-otziv__content')` gives you a collection (to map over), but `[i]` gives you a *single* node, so there's nothing to `.map` as it's not any sort of collection.

Comment: It *looks like* you want: `images_otziv = $('.customers-otziv__content').eq(i).find(".reviews__photo")` - you don't need a map on that part.  But it's unclear if that's the part that you're querying/having trouble with.

Comment: Likely off topic: If you're not using (or providing) the return value of `.map` then you don't need `.map` and should probably be using `.each`

Comment: Also unlikely to be directly related: As with your other question: `.width()` gets the width of the *first* element in the collection:  `$(document).find('.customers-otziv__content').width()`  it's unclear if that's a problem or what you intended.

Comment: customers-otziv__content classes' widthes are always const.